# Как правильно заполнить форму с помощью JS без потери данных?

Tags: php, javascript, html, frontend, backend

Как правильно заполнить форму при помощи JS и залить форму с данными в БД? Надо при соответствующим выборе выпадающего списка автоматически заполнить одно из текстовых полей. Сделал это так:

```
var select, value, text;

function change() {
    select = document.getElementById("MySelect");
    value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(value);
    if(value == "Existing Business"){
        document.getElementById("name").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        document.getElementById("name").value = "C1";
        document.getElementById("name").text = "C1";
        console.log(document.getElementById("name").text);
    }else if(value == "New Business"){
        document.getElementById("name").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        document.getElementById("name").value = "H1";
        document.getElementById("name").text = "Н1";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("name").removeAttribute('disabled');
        document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    }
}
```

На странице все отображается, но в БД ничего не попадает. Как сделать, что бы работало? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я понял. Нужно использовать readonly вместо disabled. Может кому пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Клиентская часть, может выглядеть так:

```js
var select, value, text;

function change() {
  select = document.getElementById("MySelect");
  value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(value);
  if (value == "Existing Business") {
    document.getElementById("name").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    document.getElementById("name").value = "C1";
    document.getElementById("name").text = "C1";
    console.log(document.getElementById("name").text);
  } else if (value == "New Business") {
    document.getElementById("name").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    document.getElementById("name").value = "H1";
    document.getElementById("name").text = "Н1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("name").removeAttribute('disabled');
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
  }
}

function send(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.getElementById('mainForm').elements;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Form serialization by NAME --> element must have a name attribute
  var data = Object.values(form).reduce((obj, field) => {
    // Will not send undefined or empty name attribute
    if (!(typeof field.name === "undefined" || typeof field.value === "undefined" || field.name.length === 0))
      obj[field.name] = field.value;
    return obj
  }, {});
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Send data to Server 
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'; // Replace this with your URL
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // jQuery version
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
      }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      console.log("Data Saved: ", msg);
    });

  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // No jQuery -----------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  /**
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(data);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var txt = '';
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (x in myObj) {
          txt += myObj[x].id + "<br>";
        }
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("data=" + dbParam);
    **/
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  return false;
}
```

```html
<!-------- Libraries -------->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-------- Libraries -------->
<form onsubmit="return send(event); " id="mainForm">

  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
    <select name="code" class="form-control" id="MySelect" onchange="change()">
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
      <option value="Existing Business">Existing Business</option>
      <option value="New Business">New Business</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="data" class="form-control" id="name" />
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

P.S. Открывать на весь экран.

---

Серверная часть принимает `JSON` и вносит в БД.

```
// Подключение к БД до этих команд
// Выбор таблиц и т.д.
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$statement->execute($data);
```

[Пример серверной части](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18655812)